# Should I indicate "success" of an experimental run at the beginning of the data?

Tags: predictive-models, dataset

Because I'm **that guy**, I wanted to run some statistical analysis on the results of a number of experiments; specifically, I'm wanting to track my progress on different runs of the turn-based strategy game [The Battle of Polytopia](https://polytopia.io/) in Perfection mode in order to attempt to develop a predictive model.

In Perfection mode, you have 30 turns to get the highest score that you can. At any point of the game, your score is known, so my idea is that, at the end of each turn, I'll track:

1. Which turn is ending
2. How many cities I control
3. How many points I have
4. How many stars (the unit of currency) I'll be earning at the start of the next turn

Setting aside for a moment the amount of time it'll take to gather enough data to make a worthwhile model, my question is this: in addition to taking the changing turn-by-turn data, I'll also be tracking which tribe I'm using and whether or not my score at the end of a particular run exceeds specific values (50,000, 75,000, and 100,000 points) as binary-encoded values (0 for didn't, 1 for did); as a sanity check, those unchanging values should be the same at the start of each run, yes? Like, for the score-checking columns of data, they shouldn't be 0 up until the specific score is exceeded and then switch to 1, correct?

I feel like this is a bit of a no-brainer, but I just need a sanity check.

Comment: Please consider not encoding the values, because that loses information.  Record what happens as precisely and accurately as possible and re-express your data only later, if at all, when you are analyzing them.

Comment: My idea was to have both the raw data and the encoded data as columns.

Comment: You don't need them both for simply recording the data.

Comment: I'm not just recording, I'm going to be plugging the datasets into Orange 3, and those will be the... target columns? I forget what they're called.